# Put a class with certain class in front of group of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a list of multiple divs and one of those divs will have the class current.

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> more html</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> more html </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 current"> more html </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> more html </div>
</div>
```

Now this class might be on any of the divs depending on what user was selected before. (not really relevant. just fyi)

And now I want the div with `current` to always be the first one shown in the row.

I was thinking about removing the div with jquery and then append it to the row, but I don't think this is the cleanest way.

Comment: I think it's the only way, but look into `prepend`, not `append` because this will put it at the end of the divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to use jQuery's DOM manipulation selectors to do this, but an easy one-liner is:

```
$('div.current').insertBefore('div.col-md-4:first')
```

```js
$('div.current').insertBefore('div.col-md-4:first');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> more html</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> more html </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 current"> more html</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> more html </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @WesleyvanStraalen You can check out all the jQuery DOM manipulation methods at http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `display:flex` and `order`:

```css
.row {
    display:flex; /* set flex on the parent */
}

.row .col-md-4 {
    order:2;     /* set default order to be same so they keep their original order */
}

.row .col-md-4.current {
    order:1;       /* make current a lower order so it goes to the front */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">1 more html</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2 more html </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 current">3 more html </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">4 more html </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this but does not seem to work when the html is dynamically loaded?

Comment: Seems like it messes up the bootstrap

Comment: drat, if you had used bootstrap4, row is flex by default :)

Comment: Ah, i guess it is because i have about 3-4 rows with all col-md-4 in those rows. coincidence the current class was a single column in a row. i guess it is not possible with multiple rows?

Comment: It would be possible but may mess up bootstrap styles again so probably best going with the jQuery solution, just be mindful though that your accepted solution doesn't revert the original order if you are using js to add the current class (ie if you click on multiple links to make them current without the page reloading, the current always gets put to the top and never moves back when it is no longer current, it just goes into the second position)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense thank you. i only need it to go the first one when the page is loaded so that won't be a problem. i just have a weird bugg where i get a white spot exactly the same size of a col-md-4, but it's not actually there in the DOM. also it is not the same position as current used to be

Comment: Very strange, I'd open a new question about it - but reference this question so people have a bit of context

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="order: 99">First</div>
  <div style="order: 1">Second</div>
</div>
```

This will result in `[Second, First]` order. If you want to change order then just change `element.style.order = xx` with JavaScript.

There is a good [guide on Flex from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS you could just float that particular div a different direction to the rest. I have created a fiddle you can follow.

https://jsfiddle.net/w6hhqxvq

```
.row{
   width: 100%;
}
.col-md-4{
width: 25%;
height: 200px;
background: yellow;
float: right;
}

.col-md-4.current{
float: left;
background: blue;
}
```